# Convergence result of a UI martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

[image]
[image]
[image]
This Lemma is from Ethier and Kurtz's *Markov Processes* on page 205. My question is about the equation (5.47). I can prove it is a uniformly integrable martingale (bounded by 1), so converges to a martingale a.s. and in $L^2$. But how to get the formula of the RHS of (5.47)? Thanks very much!